Grpc exception when using HttpDebugger
The following code gives me an expection on the AccessSecretVersion call, when I'm using a programm called HTTP Debugger at the same time.
    public class SecretManagerService
    {
        private readonly SecretManagerServiceClient _client;
        private readonly string                     _projectId;     
        private readonly string                     _secretName;     

        public SecretManagerService( string projectId, string secretName )
        {
            _client     = SecretManagerServiceClient.Create();
            _projectId  = projectId; 
            _secretName = secretName;
        }                   
        
        public string GetSecretValue()
        {
            HttpClient.DefaultProxy = new WebProxy();                
            var secretVersionName   = new SecretVersionName( _projectId, _secretName, "latest" );
            var secret              = _client.AccessSecretVersion( secretVersionName );
            return secret.Payload.Data.ToStringUtf8();
        }            

        public void UpdateSecretValue( string newValue )
        {
            var secretName = new SecretName( _projectId, _secretName );

            // Set the updated value
            var updatedPayload = new SecretPayload
            {
                Data = Google.Protobuf.ByteString.CopyFromUtf8( newValue )
            };

            // Update the secret
            try
            {
                _client.AddSecretVersion( secretName, updatedPayload );
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine( "    Error updating secret" );
            }
        }            
    }

Without HTTP Debugger it runs fine.
As a workaround I can start up HTTP Debugger after this call, but that becomes anooying very quickly. I need the debugger later on in the code. So I would rather fix this problem.
The exception looks like this:
    Grpc.Core.RpcException
      HResult=0x80131500
      Message=Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: Requesting HTTP version 2.0 with version policy RequestVersionOrHigher while unable to establish HTTP/2 connection.", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Requesting HTTP version 2.0 with version policy RequestVersionOrHigher while unable to establish HTTP/2 connection.")
      Source=Grpc.Net.Client
      StackTrace:
       at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.<GetResponseHeadersCoreAsync>d__72.MoveNext()
       at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.HttpClientCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
       at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.<BlockingUnaryCall>b__3_0[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest req, ClientInterceptorContext`2 ctx)
       at Grpc.Core.ClientBase.ClientBaseConfiguration.ClientBaseConfigurationInterceptor.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext`2 context, BlockingUnaryCallContinuation`2 continuation)
       at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
       at Google.Cloud.SecretManager.V1.SecretManagerService.SecretManagerServiceClient.AccessSecretVersion(AccessSecretVersionRequest request, CallOptions options)
       at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall.GrpcCallAdapter`2.CallSync(TRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
       at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCallRetryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<WithRetry>b__0(TRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
       at ....

      This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
        [External Code]

    Inner Exception 1:
    HttpRequestException: Requesting HTTP version 2.0 with version policy RequestVersionOrHigher while unable to establish HTTP/2 connection.

I've already asked ChatGPT, and it indicated that I should try to use HTTP 1.1, but unfortunatly it didn't give any usable code.

It sounds like your HTTP debugger doesn't support HTTP/2. gRPC requires† HTTP/2, so: that's not going to work.

†: I'm ignoring exotic transports here and referring to the standard gRPC experience
